# Python: Sliding windowed mean, ignoring missing data

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, time-series, missing-data

I am currently trying to process an experimental timeseries dataset, which has missing values. I would like to calculate the sliding windowed mean of this dataset along time, while handling nan values. The correct way for me to do it is to compute inside each window the sum of the finite elements and divide it with their number. This nonlinearity forces me to use non convolutional methods to face this problem, thus I have a severe time bottleneck in this part of the process. As a code example of what I am trying to accomplish I present the following:

```
import numpy as np
#Construct sample data
n = 50
n_miss = 20
win_size = 3
data= np.random.random(50)
data[np.random.randint(0,n-1, n_miss)] = None

#Compute mean
result = np.zeros(data.size)
for count in range(data.size):
    part_data = data[max(count - (win_size - 1) / 2, 0): min(count + (win_size + 1) / 2, data.size)]
    mask = np.isfinite(part_data)
    if np.sum(mask) != 0:
        result[count] = np.sum(part_data[mask]) / np.sum(mask)
    else:
        result[count] = None
print 'Input:\t',data
print 'Output:\t',result
```

with output:

```
Input:  [ 0.47431791  0.17620835  0.78495647  0.79894688  0.58334064  0.38068788
  0.87829696         nan  0.71589171         nan  0.70359557  0.76113969
  0.13694387  0.32126573  0.22730891         nan  0.35057169         nan
  0.89251851  0.56226354  0.040117           nan  0.37249799  0.77625334
         nan         nan         nan         nan  0.63227417  0.92781944
  0.99416471  0.81850753  0.35004997         nan  0.80743783  0.60828597
         nan  0.01410721         nan         nan  0.6976317          nan
  0.03875394  0.60924066  0.22998065         nan  0.34476729  0.38090961
         nan  0.2021964 ]
Output: [ 0.32526313  0.47849424  0.5867039   0.72241466  0.58765847  0.61410849
  0.62949242  0.79709433  0.71589171  0.70974364  0.73236763  0.53389305
  0.40644977  0.22850617  0.27428732  0.2889403   0.35057169  0.6215451
  0.72739103  0.49829968  0.30119027  0.20630749  0.57437567  0.57437567
  0.77625334         nan         nan  0.63227417  0.7800468   0.85141944
  0.91349722  0.7209074   0.58427875  0.5787439   0.7078619   0.7078619
  0.31119659  0.01410721  0.01410721  0.6976317   0.6976317   0.36819282
  0.3239973   0.29265842  0.41961066  0.28737397  0.36283845  0.36283845
  0.29155301  0.2021964 ]
```

Can this result be produced by numpy operations, without using a for loop?

Comment: Have you considered reindexing and interpolating the data frame to have a linear index and use [`rolling`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html) later?

Comment: If I understood correctly, this will not produce the wanted result. I do not want to ignore the existence of the nan values, their position matters. If I have 3 nans one after another, the result in the middle element with a sliding window of 3 should be nan. Please explain, if I got you wrong.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't read your question right at all! :S

Comment: `numpy/lib/nanfunctions.py` has the main and helper functions for calculating things without the `nan` values.  For example `nanmean` uses `arr, mask = _replace_nan(a, 0)` and calculates `mean=sum(arr)/sum(mask)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a convolution based approach using [`np.convolve`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.convolve.html) -

```
mask = np.isnan(data)
K = np.ones(win_size,dtype=int)
out = np.convolve(np.where(mask,0,data), K)/np.convolve(~mask,K)
```

Please note that this would have one extra element on either sides.

If you are working with `2D` data, we can use [`Scipy's 2D convolution`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.18.1/reference/generated/scipy.signal.convolve2d.html).

Approaches -

```
def original_app(data, win_size):
    #Compute mean
    result = np.zeros(data.size)
    for count in range(data.size):
        part_data = data[max(count - (win_size - 1) / 2, 0): \
                 min(count + (win_size + 1) / 2, data.size)]
        mask = np.isfinite(part_data)
        if np.sum(mask) != 0:
            result[count] = np.sum(part_data[mask]) / np.sum(mask)
        else:
            result[count] = None
    return result

def numpy_app(data, win_size):     
    mask = np.isnan(data)
    K = np.ones(win_size,dtype=int)
    out = np.convolve(np.where(mask,0,data), K)/np.convolve(~mask,K)
    return out[1:-1]  # Slice out the one-extra elems on sides
```

Sample run -

```
In [118]: #Construct sample data
     ...: n = 50
     ...: n_miss = 20
     ...: win_size = 3
     ...: data= np.random.random(50)
     ...: data[np.random.randint(0,n-1, n_miss)] = np.nan
     ...: 

In [119]: original_app(data, win_size = 3)
Out[119]: 
array([ 0.88356487,  0.86829731,  0.85249541,  0.83776219,         nan,
               nan,  0.61054015,  0.63111926,  0.63111926,  0.65169837,
        0.1857301 ,  0.58335324,  0.42088104,  0.5384565 ,  0.31027752,
        0.40768907,  0.3478563 ,  0.34089655,  0.55462903,  0.71784816,
        0.93195716,         nan,  0.41635575,  0.52211653,  0.65053379,
        0.76762282,  0.72888574,  0.35250449,  0.35250449,  0.14500637,
        0.06997668,  0.22582318,  0.18621848,  0.36320784,  0.19926647,
        0.24506199,  0.09983572,  0.47595439,  0.79792941,  0.5982114 ,
        0.42389375,  0.28944089,  0.36246113,  0.48088139,  0.71105449,
        0.60234163,  0.40012839,  0.45100475,  0.41768466,  0.41768466])

In [120]: numpy_app(data, win_size = 3)
__main__:36: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in divide
Out[120]: 
array([ 0.88356487,  0.86829731,  0.85249541,  0.83776219,         nan,
               nan,  0.61054015,  0.63111926,  0.63111926,  0.65169837,
        0.1857301 ,  0.58335324,  0.42088104,  0.5384565 ,  0.31027752,
        0.40768907,  0.3478563 ,  0.34089655,  0.55462903,  0.71784816,
        0.93195716,         nan,  0.41635575,  0.52211653,  0.65053379,
        0.76762282,  0.72888574,  0.35250449,  0.35250449,  0.14500637,
        0.06997668,  0.22582318,  0.18621848,  0.36320784,  0.19926647,
        0.24506199,  0.09983572,  0.47595439,  0.79792941,  0.5982114 ,
        0.42389375,  0.28944089,  0.36246113,  0.48088139,  0.71105449,
        0.60234163,  0.40012839,  0.45100475,  0.41768466,  0.41768466])
```

Runtime test -

```
In [122]: #Construct sample data
     ...: n = 50000
     ...: n_miss = 20000
     ...: win_size = 3
     ...: data= np.random.random(n)
     ...: data[np.random.randint(0,n-1, n_miss)] = np.nan
     ...: 

In [123]: %timeit original_app(data, win_size = 3)
1 loops, best of 3: 1.51 s per loop

In [124]: %timeit numpy_app(data, win_size = 3)
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.09 ms per loop

In [125]: import pandas as pd

# @jdehesa's pandas solution
In [126]: %timeit pd.Series(data).rolling(window=3, min_periods=1).mean()
100 loops, best of 3: 3.34 ms per loop
```

Comment: This is giving me as far as I can tell the right location of NaNs, but it does not compute correctly the values, whose sliding window includes nans. Correct me if I am wrong, with an example if possible, thank you.

Comment: @VasilisLemonidis Added one.

Comment: Ok , this is the best answer, convolving the nominators and denominators separately seems to work without problems. The only thing that puzzles me, which can easily be fixed but I do not have the slightest idea why it is happening, is that the nans inside your result have too many values (??). If I do something like `np.sum(np.isnan(np.unique(np_res)))` for the result of your implementation, I get a non unary result. I guess there must be an uneven handling of zero divisions in numpy or something like that.

Comment: And as far as the 2D implementation is considered, I believe that np.apply_along_axis should be used, as it is faster than scipy operation, am I not right?

Comment: @VasilisLemonidis Well `np.unique()` doesn't work on array filled with NaNs. To test, run `np.unique` on a NaN filled array : `np.unique(np.full(10,np.nan))`. It won't get you one NaN, you will get all 10 `NaNs`. On `2D`, `apply_along_axis` isnt for performance, I would go with Scipy's 2D and using a 2D kernel as `np.ones((win_size,win_size)dtype=int)`.

Comment: Ok, `np.unique` doesn't work with nans, but if I do something like `numpy_app(data)[numpy_app(data) != original_app(data)]` and `original_app(data)[numpy_app(data) != original_app(data)]` I get an array of nans in both cases, which is not logical, so I guess there must be 2 types of nan at least. By refering to the `2D` case, I would like to apply this operation on time axis only, with axis=1 being the feature space and  axis=0 being the time space. If the array was an image, I would use definitely a scipy or a cython implementation. Thank you for taking the time to answer my question

Comment: @VasilisLemonidis OK, so I am sensing you are trying to verify results. If you are asking me how to do so, I would do this : `np.nanmax(np.abs(a - b))`

Comment: @VasilisLemonidis And also do this : `np.array_equal(np.isnan(a), np.isnan(b))`.

Comment: Yes, haha, your sensing was correct, any aberration would destroy my results. Thank you! :D

Answer (score 7):

You can do that using the [`rolling`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html) function of Pandas:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

#Construct sample data
n = 50
n_miss = 20
win_size = 3
data = np.random.random(n)
data[np.random.randint(0, n-1, n_miss)] = None

windowed_mean = pd.Series(data).rolling(window=win_size, min_periods=1).mean()

print(pd.DataFrame({'Data': data, 'Windowed mean': windowed_mean}) )
```

Output:

```
        Data  Windowed mean
0   0.589376       0.589376
1   0.639173       0.614274
2   0.343534       0.524027
3   0.250329       0.411012
4   0.911952       0.501938
5        NaN       0.581141
6   0.224964       0.568458
7        NaN       0.224964
8   0.508419       0.366692
9   0.215418       0.361918
10       NaN       0.361918
11  0.638118       0.426768
12  0.587478       0.612798
13  0.097037       0.440878
14  0.688689       0.457735
15  0.858593       0.548107
16  0.408903       0.652062
17  0.448993       0.572163
18       NaN       0.428948
19  0.877453       0.663223
20       NaN       0.877453
21       NaN       0.877453
22  0.021798       0.021798
23  0.482054       0.251926
24  0.092387       0.198746
25  0.251766       0.275402
26  0.093854       0.146002
27       NaN       0.172810
28       NaN       0.093854
29       NaN            NaN
30  0.965669       0.965669
31  0.695999       0.830834
32       NaN       0.830834
33       NaN       0.695999
34       NaN            NaN
35  0.613727       0.613727
36  0.837533       0.725630
37       NaN       0.725630
38  0.782295       0.809914
39       NaN       0.782295
40  0.777429       0.779862
41  0.401355       0.589392
42  0.491709       0.556831
43  0.127813       0.340292
44  0.781625       0.467049
45  0.960466       0.623301
46  0.637618       0.793236
47  0.651264       0.749782
48  0.154911       0.481264
49  0.159145       0.321773
```

Comment: This is beautiful. I wonder, can this operation be used with 2d arrays? I have not used pandas at all, neither installed the module. Can you please also provide me with some timings, in order to compare your implementation with the for-loop implementation?

Comment: Oh and by the way, is the convolution forward by default? I mean, the result is taken by the current and the previous n-1 elements, not from the next  and the previous `(n-1)/2` ones.

Comment: @VasilisLemonidis Yes, the mean is computed forwards (see, for example, that in my output `NaN` appears on the right only *after* three `NaN` in the left). As for performance, I just timed with n = 10,000 and the average is ~1.2ms. `rolling` can be used in both 1D arrays ([`Series`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.19.2/generated/pandas.Series.html)) and in 2D arrays ([`DataFrame`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.19.2/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html)) either column-wise or row-wise (if you are asking for something else please clarify).

Comment: @VasilisLemonidis Just to be clearer, [`rolling` supports many opperations](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.19.2/api.html#window), and if you need some kind of special mean, for example, you could also use [`rolling(...).apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.19.2/generated/pandas.core.window.Rolling.apply.html#pandas.core.window.Rolling.apply).

Comment: No, you have covered all of my questions. I will wait a little before bestvoting your question, in case anyone else has thought of anything else. Thank you!

Comment: I used this solution. Worked perfectly for me